# puzzling declarations in simd code of fftw

Tags: simd, avx, fftw, avx2

In head files of simd of fftw3, such as simd-generic128.h and simd-generic256.h, STM2, STN2, STM4, STN4 are decleared. What operation do they do in fftw?

I found that some of them lack implementations, such as STN2 and STM4 in simd-generic128.h, and STM2 and STM4 in simd-generic256.h. Does the lake of them cause problems? When I implement simd on a new architecture, I need to implement which of them?

```
#define STM2 ST
#define STN2(x, v0, v1, ovs) /* nop */
static inline void STN4(R *x, V v0, V v1, V v2, V v3, INT ovs)
{
  ...
}
#define STM4(x, v, ovs, aligned_like) /* no-op */
```

Comment: From the [documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Generating-your-own-code.html): "We do not provide more details about the code-generation process, since we do not expect that most users will need to generate their own code. However, feel free to contact us at fftw@fftw.org if you are interested in the subject."

Comment: If you do email them, perhaps point them at this SO Q&A to give them a place to answer publicly.  Or let them know that you can post their response here (or what worked for you based on it) if they'd rather just email.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reminding. I will email the developers for more details.